# Flask - getting 500 errors with DELETE

Tags: python, flask

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but here it is:

```
@app.route(PREFIX + '/<table>/<int:index>', methods = ['DELETE'])
def delete_row(table, index=None):
    if table not in can_delete:
        abort(404)
    try:
        del database[table][index]
    except:
        abort(404)
    print('returning')
```

And here's the result of running it:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
returning
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015 11:28:44] "DELETE /api/json/types/ig-folders/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015 11:29:01] "DELETE /api/json/types/ig-folders/99 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015 11:28:35] "DELETE /api/json/types/invalid/1 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

My GET handlers work OK, and the DELETE handler is working OK except for the pesky 500 error.  Is the issue that I'm not returning any values?  I was under the impression that DELETE should only return a status, not data.

Comment: What's the error on the 500? It could be anything.

Comment: I'm wanting to return a 200.

Comment: DELETE should either return status 200 *and* a response body, or status 204 (no content)

Comment: Oh.  The spec for the REST app I'm using specified 200 with no data on success.  Let me try returning a 204 instead.  Nope, "abort(204)" still gives me a 500.  Again, the data is getting deleted.

Comment: Why are you using `del`? Just...why?  You really shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Because I'm deleting a row from my mock "database".  It's not SQL, just a dict (indexed by table name) of lists of rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not returning a response when the deletion is successful. The 500 is thrown because `None` is not a valid return value for a Flask view.

Return [an acceptable response type](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#about-responses), like a string, instead.

For a 200 response, you could return:

```
'Success', 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
```

or you could return a [204 *No Content*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5), where you'd return an empty string for the response body:

```
'', 204
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that returning a standard 200 (OK) response code from a DELETE action still expects a response body. You must either return a response or status code 204 (NO CONTENT).